# Correct pattern to split GWT code

Tags: java, gwt, module, code-splitting

I've a lot of forms in my GWT app, each form may just be loaded when client clicks on its icon in the program, but I used some static members in each class everywhere in my code.
For avoiding heavy initialize code downloading, I've splitted my code, something like this :

```
public class baseForm 
{
    public static final int id = 0;
    ...
};

public class form1 extends baseForm 
{
    public static final int id = 1;
    ...
};

public class form2 extends baseForm 
{
    public static final int id = 2;
    ...
};

public class myModule extends SmartGwtEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        if(some_condition == form1.id)
        {
           GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                LogUtil.logException(caught);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                new form1().show();
            }
        });
        }
        else
        {
           GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                LogUtil.logException(caught);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                new form2().show();
            }
        });
        }
    }
};
```

Is it a correct solution which load non-static content of form1 & form2 according to the initial condition?
What about static members & contents?
And what happens for base form? is that base code loads only one time when first form is loaded or it loads for both of them?